# Can "debriefing" mean undressing a person?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [Our Nuclear Policies are Crazier than Trump](https://foreignpolicy.com/2016/08/05/our-nuclear-procedures-are-crazier-than-trump/), there's mention of "what if the president is debriefing an intern?" as an example of a president being busy:

> What is amazing about these timelines is how much time is lost to
>   purely mechanical or administrative steps, from detecting the launches
>   to finding the president. What if the president is asleep? Playing
>   golf? In the toilet? Debriefing an intern?

Based on the author's specific choice of "intern", I'm wondering if there's any double entendre involved beyond the normal meaning of receiving information, and is referring to a president taking off the underwear of an intern. However, I thought briefs are male underwear, and the bulk of the allegations against Bill Clinton and Donald Trump involve women.

Can "debriefing" mean the undressing of a person?

Comment: When applied to a president and an intern, I would take it as a double entendre or pun aimed at Bill Clinton

Comment: Yeah, it's a double entendre/euphemism.

Comment: Womens' briefs (underwear):  https://www.amazon.com/Womens-Briefs/b?ie=UTF8&node=1044972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for briefs to refer to women's clothing, so the double entendre works here. From [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/briefs):

> men's underpants or women's pants without legs

Comment: Why the downvote? Do you dislike questions about sexuality? Do you dislike self-answered questions? Or the fact that people commented on the question - but I actually got a reference backing up the claims made in the comments.

Comment: I've never heard anyone refer to women's pants as "briefs"... Only men's underwear.

Comment: @Catija - http://www.google.com/search?q=women%E2%80%99s+briefs&oq=women%E2%80%99s+briefs&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3...2064.8039.0.9203.17.10.0.6.6.0.178.1288.0j8.8.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-serp..6.11.1324.Ye1SQBu8NuU. (not women’s pants, but women’s underwear)